# Swift, load data into temp file stream for transferFile

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Is it possible to load a `[String : Any]` dictionary into a temporary file stream, without writing the contents to disk anywhere, then feed the stream to `transferFile`, as the file parameter? I know this is possible in PHP, but am not so sure about Swift.

I have come across a problem whereby my data exceeds the messaging limits. Therefore I either need to develop my own protocol to transfer the data, or somehow pass the data to `transferFile`.

I do not want to write my data to temporary files, transfer, and then delete them, as this is pretty dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write the contents of the dictionary to a temporary file and pass the URL of that file to `transferFile`? I know you think that this is a "dirty" way to do things but since you need to pass a file URL to `transferFile`, that might be your only option - at least, that's the only option I know of ...

Comment: Well there is also the option of doing multiple user info transfers, with a header containing chunk position, and total block size. Then you reconstruct it in the iOS app. Which approach do you think is better? I suppose I could use a single temp file that I keep creating and removing to store the buffer.

Comment: Personally, I tend to go for the simpler option :) So, as long as you don't have the need to create multiple temporary files at the same time, I think having one temporary file that you overwrite each time would probably be the simpler and easier option.

Of course, since I don't know all your requirements, I might be totally wrong :)